# Struts 2 + Java Bean not retaining values

Tags: jsp, null, struts2, javabeans, ognl

Firstly, I'm using Struts 2 and Java. I'm trying to get my `LoginUser` Action Class to pass information to the `UserBean` Java Bean.

When the `LoginUser` Action executes, the bean value for `fullName` is displayed by calling it from the `userBean` via the `<s:property>` tag.

However when I click the `More Info` link in the `success.jsp`, the following page also calls the bean value `fullName` via the `<s:property>` tag, but this time it is `null` and if I go back the the `success.jsp` it is also `null`.

**MY QUESTION:**

Why is the bean not retaining the information like it's meant to?

Technical notes:  I am developing using Eclipse IDE as a Maven project and only have Apache Tomcat 7 to use to test/deploy with.

**CODE FROM JAVA AND JSP FILES:**

**`LoginUser` ACTION:**

```
package test.Home1;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class LoginUser {

    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String userOK = "admin";
    private String passOK = "admin";
    
//  Password getters/setters    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
//  Username getters/setters
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
     
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
//  Bean is instantiated here
    private UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
    
//  userBean getters/setters    
    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
    this.userBean = userBean;
    }
    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
}
    
//  Execute the following action when this class is called via struts action
    public String execute() {
        
        if (this.username.equalsIgnoreCase(userOK) && this.password.equals(passOK)) {
            
            userBean.setAccessLevel("full");
            userBean.setFullName("Administrator");
            userBean.setUserName(username);
            
        return "SUCCESS";

    }
        else {
            return "FAIL";
        }
        }
}
```

**`UserBean` BEAN:**

```
package Test.Home1;
    
public class UserBean {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    private String accessLevel;
    private boolean LoggedIn = false;
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getAccessLevel() {
        return accessLevel;
    }
    public void setAccessLevel(String accessLevel) {
        this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
    }
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return LoggedIn;
    }
    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        LoggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
    
}
```

**`login.jsp` JSP Form Login Page:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello World at Home (Struts 2 Tutorial)
</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
<h1>Please Log in</h1>

<s:form action="LoginUser" autocomplete="off">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
    
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**`success.jsp` JSP Login Successful Page:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello World at Home (Struts 2 Tutorial) - LOGGED IN
</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
<h1>Struts 2 Hello World Example</h1>
<h4>Hello <s:property value="userBean.fullName" />
</h4>
<br><br>
<s:a value="Info">More Info</s:a>
</body>
</html>
```

**`moreInfo.jsp` JSP FILE:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello World at Home (Struts 2 Tutorial) - LOGGED IN
</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
<h1>Are you still there <s:property value="userBean.fullName" />?</h1>

<h4>Can you still see your name above?</h4>
<br><br>
<s:a value="Home">Home</s:a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Action beans live only during the same request, but if you press on the link then it invokes another request where the `userBean` is *not* created. Struts populate the bean if it's `null` when you submit the form.

The default behavior of the OGNL when it's trying to populate the bean from expression which includes a parameter name is `createIfNull==true`. Since you didn't supply any parameters with the bean name then nothing is populated.

If you add some parameter like in this code

```
<s:a action="ShowUser"><s:param name="userBean.fullName" value="Administrator"/> More Info</s:a>
```

then it would create a `userBean` and initialize its property `fullName` with the value of the parameter. The action name should be different and it should map to another method instead of `execute()` which is used by default if no method attribute is specified in the action configuration.

**References:**

- [`<s:a>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/a-tag.html)
- [`<s:param>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/param-tag.html)
- [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html)